# $\int_{-\infty}^2 \frac{x}{(x-2)^{1/3}}dx$ convergence or divergence?

Tags: calculus

$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^2 \dfrac{x}{(x-2)^{1/3}}dx$

I first try to apply $x\to -x$ transformation so

$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^2 \dfrac{x}{(x-2)^{1/3}}dx\to -\displaystyle\int^{\infty}_{-2} \dfrac{x}{(x+2)^{1/3}}dx$

I think $\displaystyle\int^{\infty}_{-2} \dfrac{x}{(x+2)^{1/3}}dx$ I may transform this into series form and using series test to show it is divergent but couldnot.

Comment: What is the limit of the integrand as $x \to -\infty$?

Comment: I don't understand why there is a question.  $|\frac{x}{(x-2)^{1/3}}|\to \infty$ as $|x|\to \infty$.

Comment: I want to know proper way to show it,  I thought there is an counter example $\lim f(x)\to \infty$  but may be improper integral convergences

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{x}{(x-2)^{1/3}} \sim x^{\frac{2}{3}}$$
when $x \to -\infty$